# How can I download interactive images?

Tags: javascript, python, image, download

Is there a way to download static image from a website which has an interactive image using python? I am trying to download images of a car from all possible angles from this website [Toyota](https://www.toyotabharat.com/virtual-showroom/innova.html) for a computer vision project.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup and Selenium both can load can capture images from a website that uses dynamic data using Python. I would do some research into that.